# PDF Download option in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have installed Miktex and Pandoc, followed by that when I try to download the notebook in PDF, I get the pop up to install missing packages. It says, the package will be retrieved from this source 'Random package repository'. I am new to Python so wanted to check if it was safe to go ahead and click Install.
[image]

Comment: Hi Abdulla! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Your tags are wrong.

Jupyter (nbconvert) is most likely functional as it is calling Pandoc

Likewise Python is most likely functional otherwise Pandoc Filters should not be calling MiKTeX

MiKTeX is most likely functional otherwise you would not be getting the warning.

MiKTeX is a very trimmed down specialist version of LiveTeX.

That warning is from the MiKTeX package manager. It's nothing to do with Python or Jupyter. The file requested is a LiveTeX.sty file and the random repository could be anywhere in the world, but most likely one in your own country or even the local university.

It can be a CTAN site or a dedicated MiKTeX site, the reason many such updates are required can be either a new version or a missing dependency from the trimmed down TeX file set.

You may get repeated requests to update TeX components early on in your usage, because MiKTeX is probably set correctly to "Install on Demand" and any (PDF)LaTeX application such as PanDoc may need many first use packages.